# Something Commonly Searched For

Tags: visual, connect-wall

This is a standard PSE connect wall in that you must find four groups of four.

Then find the commonality between those four groups (not a word that fits into all four groups, as some connect walls require). The title refers to that commonality.

<sub>This is my first connect wall, so I got a couple rounds of feedback from a knowledgeable friend and altered this puzzle accordingly.</sub>

[image]

**Tips:**

- This wall contains a few US-centric terms, so it might be easier for Americans.
- No words need to be flipped (reversed).
- [Here are the word frequencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IHgx.png) for the past 100 years for some of the rarer words in the grid. (Clarification: These frequencies are for the words **as they relate to the connection**, not the word from the image. This is a good hint within itself.)

**EDIT: Sept 9, 2022:**

- Added in word lengths to each of the 16 images.
- Added A1Z26 checksums per row (top to bottom): 117, 130, 204, 205
- Added clarification under the frequencies bullet point above.

Comment: Could you perhaps link the tool was used to calculate the frequencies? Might be helpful for people to double check their guesses

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, @Stiv! @BeastlyGerbil I would provide the link, but it is not a standalone tool. I got it from the Collins English DIctionary. Here is the link for gerbil. See the frequency trend by scrolling about 60% of the way down. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gerbil

Comment: At least from my POV, but I imagine same for others, the tricky bit (which I think is pretty much the same for any connect wall) is knowing if you have the correct words or not, some sort of validation of the words, length, a given character, something like that would probably be the best/most appropriate hint I reckon. Me personally I haven't found a single group of 4 yet as I'm just not sure on the words

Comment: Yeah, the 16 words - it can be hard to get an intended word from a single picture as theres so many possibilities, whereas it's much easier to get a group name from 4 words as thats rather limited. Theres probably a few different hints you could add, whichever you deem more appropriate I just recommend making the hints about the 16 words to start :)

Comment: Well I have the correct 16 words, and now I'm struggling to get the categories :P But the hints are perfect to make progress with! Not too obvious as there's a few with multiple possibilities, but it is still possible to get them

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil My tester got 14 of the 16 with no hint, and for the 2 that were missed, I added words into the image to clarify, so I was hoping that would be enough, but I totally understand people not wanting to try to find connections if they are not near 100% sure that the word is the intended word, so I added the hints today.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I had struggled to find the words, because I thought the frequencies related to the original words depicted in the grid. For example, for the picture that clearly shows a leg, I tried the rather obscure "gam", which I know only from crosswords, and got a frequency that was higher than the one shown. Now most of the words are write-ins. (But I'm still missing one and since BG is stuck, I don't expect to get far.)

Comment: @MOehm keep your head up! you got this!

Comment: I also just realised, the two frequencies marked 2007 are identical. I'm assuming this is an error? I have one of the connections for these, and can't see how the other would give the same term

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Updated- The frequency in the 3rd col 3rd row is now correct. That is not that rare of a word, is it!? ok, good luck.

Comment: @JLee perfect thanks, I have two groups so that should help me crack the last 2!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The words are:

> RAIN, FLAG, BRA, AIR
> STAR, CAB, PAY, LEG
> HEAD, CROSS, BULLET, BOARD
> HERO, POOL, TOWN, HAT

And the groups are then:

> *-SHIP*:  **Flag**-ship, **town**-ship, **star**-ship and **air**-ship
> *-CHECK*:  **Pay**-check, **rain**-check, [**hat**-check](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hatcheck) and [**cross**-check](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crosscheck) 
> *-IN*:     **Bullet**-in, **hero**-in, **cab**-in and **bra**-in
> *-ROOM*:   **Leg**-room, **pool**-room, **head**-room and **board**-room

So the final connection between these 4 groups is:

> **MATE** - something commonly searched for!
>
> As *-MATE* can be appended to the groups: **ship**-mate, **check**-mate, **in**-mate and **room**-mate!